# How to add a jQuery plugin in theme?

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I have been looking into RequireJS for a while, but till now, I still can not figure out how to add the [TouchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html) plugin into my theme.

Would somebody take the time to give me a step by step?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

copy js file jquery.touchSwipe.min.js into your custom theme **`web/js`** folder.

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js**

Now you have to use inside your template file,

just create requirejs-config.js file inside your theme template,

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

code for js file,

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'touchswipe': "js/jquery.touchSwipe.min"
        },   
    shim: {
        'touchswipe': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can use inside your template like this,

```
<div id="touchme">Touch me to see effect</div>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'touchswipe'
    ], function($, swipe){
        $(function() {
            $("#touchme").swipe({
                    //keep your code here
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now

```
Remove var folder from root
Remove pub/static folder contents.
```

Run deploy command,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: removing the static folder removed .htaccess which breaks the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Copy **jquery.touchSwipe.js**
following location

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/jquery.touchSwipe.js
```

Now inside phtml template you just add following line. [This is the basic example.](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Basic_swipe.html)

```
<div id="test" class="box">Swipe me</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.touchSwipe'
    ], function($, swipe){
        $(function() {
            //Enable swiping...
            $("#test").swipe({
                //Generic swipe handler for all directions
                swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
                    $(this).text("You swiped " + direction);
                },
                //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
                threshold: 0
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create requirejs-config.js under CompanyName\Custom\view\frontend\ folder with the following code -:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            jquery_cookie:           'CompanyName_Custom/js/jquery_cookie',
        }
    }
};
```

Step 2: Add jquery_cookie.js or any other jquery plugin under CompanyName\Custom\view\frontend\web\js\

Step 3: Now the jquery plugin has been added, now you can call jquery cookie plugin from any of your template files

```
<script>
        //<![CDATA[
        require(['jquery','jquery_cookie'], function($){
            $(window).load(function() {
                $.cookie.json = true;
                var customCookie = $.cookie("customCookie");

                if (customCookie != undefined) {
                    console.log(customCookie);
                    $.removeCookie("customCookie", {path: '/', domain: document.domain});
                }
            });
        });
        //]]>
</script>
```

The key thing to notice here is that we are using require JS as part of the first line ***require([‘jquery’,’jquery_cookie’]*** and declaring to use jquery and our newly added jquery plugin i.e. jquery_cookie.

Hope this helps!